# push notification to multiple devices using SNS

Tags: php, android, ios, push-notification, amazon-sns

We were using UrbanAirship earlier to send notifications to iOS and Android devices. There is possibility to send same message to multiple devices (both including iOS and Android). Adding multiple device tokens to same payload and one message for all device types. The payload is

```
{"audience":{"OR":[{"apid":"12345"},{"apid":"34526"},{"apid":"844641"}{"device_token":"23423423", "device_token":"454343"}]},"notification":{"alert":"You got a new feed","android":{"extra":{"page":"feeds","feed_id":"109"}},"ios":{"extra":{"page":"feeds","feed_id":"109"}}},"device_types":["ios","android"]}
```

Can anyone help me to mimic the same here in Amazon SNS using PHP. To send same message/alert to multiple device tokens of different OS with some extra parameters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557179/sending-amazon-sns-from-my-php-server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending Amazon SNS from my PHP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557179/sending-amazon-sns-from-my-php-server)