# Got error when trying to push via AWS SNS "Wrong number of slashes in relative portion of the ARN."

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I try to adapt the source from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557179/sending-amazon-sns-from-my-php-server) but it return error "Wrong number of slashes in relative portion of the ARN." I google it but can't find any related to this error. what should I do to make a publish.

```
    <?php

require '<path to this file>/aws.phar';
use Aws\Sns\SnsClient;

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $push_message = $_POST['push_message'];

    if(!empty($push_message))
    {
        // Create a new Amazon SNS client
        $sns = SnsClient::factory(array(
            'key'    => '<access key>',
            'secret' => '<app secret>',
            'region' => '<region code>'
            ));

        // region code samples: us-east-1, ap-northeast-1, sa-east-1, ap-southeast-1, ap-southeast-2, us-west-2, us-gov-west-1, us-west-1, cn-north-1, eu-west-1

        $iOS_AppArn = "<iOS app's Application ARN>";
        $android_AppArn = "<android app's Application ARN>";

        // Get the application's endpoints
        $iOS_model = $sns->listEndpointsByPlatformApplication(array('PlatformApplicationArn' => $iOS_AppArn));
        $android_model = $sns->listEndpointsByPlatformApplication(array('PlatformApplicationArn' => $android_AppArn));

        // Display all of the endpoints for the iOS application
        foreach ($iOS_model['Endpoints'] as $endpoint)
        {
            $endpointArn = $endpoint['EndpointArn'];
            echo $endpointArn;
        }

        // Display all of the endpoints for the android application
        foreach ($iOS_model['Endpoints'] as $endpoint)
        {
            $endpointArn = $endpoint['EndpointArn'];
            echo $endpointArn;
        }

        // iOS: Send a message to each endpoint
        foreach ($iOS_model['Endpoints'] as $endpoint)
        {
            $endpointArn = $endpoint['EndpointArn'];

            try
            {
                $sns->publish(array('Message' => $push_message,
                    'TargetArn' => $endpointArn));

                echo "<strong>Success:</strong> ".$endpointArn."<br/>";
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                echo "<strong>Failed:</strong> ".$endpointArn."<br/><strong>Error:</strong> ".$e->getMessage()."<br/>";
            }
        }

        // android: Send a message to each endpoint
        foreach ($android_model['Endpoints'] as $endpoint)
        {
            $endpointArn = $endpoint['EndpointArn'];

            try
            {
                $sns->publish(array('Message' => $push_message,
                    'TargetArn' => $endpointArn));

                echo "<strong>Success:</strong> ".$endpointArn."<br/>";
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                echo "<strong>Failed:</strong> ".$endpointArn."<br/><strong>Error:</strong> ".$e->getMessage()."<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: Have you examined these endpoint ARNs to see what they look like?  An example, apparently, is `arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:endpoint/GCM/gcmpushapp/5e3e9847-3183-3f18-a7e8-671c3a57d4b3` from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/APIReference/API_CreatePlatformEndpoint.html

Comment: my end point look like 

arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:123456789012:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/myappName/17288bc3-f6eb-3cd8-b5cc-e4b1d728880e